# What is the point of making relation in phpmyadmin database designer?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I understand some basics about relational database. But I don't get the point of making relation through phpmyadmin designer. What is the benefit there when I have to query any related table with another table's content ID? 
[image: Here is my database architecture]

When I make any query to select post where user_id=1, is there any way to make it like that, I will select from user_list where id=1, and I don't have to make another query to table posts?

Comment: You've asked 2 very different questions. To answer the first one about why, it allows you to visualize the relationship and refine it if necessary before you start writing any code. You would probably get a better response to the 2nd question if you asked it separately along with code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question: It documents the relationships for reference, and most designer applications will generate constraints enforcing those relationships.

To your answer your second question, no. If you only want information from posts, there would be no reason to involve users_list unless it relied on information from there, such as wanting to know "posts made by any users with the first name 'bob'"; in which case you would use a join. But if you already know the id for the user, there is no reason to involve users_list.